Not seeing Map Elevation with Pydeck
I am using topojson map data.
Essentially I expect to see elevation of each Zone's height based on the data_count value. But I see all zones in equal height. get_elevation in place of get_elevation_weight shows 2D map.
As in the image the count values are different left:659, right:250 but the elevation looks the same
My code snippet looks like:
with open(topojson_file) as f:
        topojson_data = json.load(f)

# Editing TopoJSON with data counts from csv data
for zone in topojson_data['features']:
    division_name = zone['properties'].get('division', 'Unknown')
    data_count = division_data_counts.get(division_name, 0)
    zone['properties']['data_count'] = data_count

geojson_layer = pdk.Layer(
    "GeoJsonLayer",
    topojson_data,
    opacity=0.6,
    stroked=False,
    filled=True,
    extruded=True,
    get_fill_color="[data_count * 10, 150, 200]",
    get_elevation_weight="data_count * 100",
    pickable=True,
    auto_highlight=True,
)

view_state = pdk.ViewState(
    latitude=data['latitude'].mean(),
    longitude=data['longitude'].mean(),
    zoom=7,
    pitch=60,
)

r = pdk.Deck(
    layers=[geojson_layer],
    initial_view_state=view_state,
    tooltip={
        "html": "<b>Zone:</b> {division}<br/><b>Data Count:</b> {data_count}",
        "style": {"color": "white"}
    }
)`

data_count is defined elsewhere which I have no problem with. There is no issue with my data:
This is loading my data_count directly on pydeck without the topo_json

I got it resolved. Look up the property: zone_code in zone_to_division.
    for feature in topojson_data['features']:
        division_name = feature['properties'].get('division', 'Unknown')
        zone_code = next((k for k, v in zone_to_division.items() if v == division_name), None)
        
        if zone_code and zone_code in zone_colors:
            feature['properties']['color'] = zone_colors[zone_code]
            feature['properties']['data_count'] = division_crime_counts.get(division_name, 0)
        else:
            feature['properties']['color'] = [200, 200, 200]
            feature['properties']['data_count'] = 0

    geojson_layer = pdk.Layer(
        "GeoJsonLayer",
        topojson_data,
        opacity=0.6,
        stroked=True,
        filled=True,
        extruded=True,
        get_fill_color='properties.color',
        get_elevation='properties.crime_count * 100',
    ...

Here's my output
